# Why spring-boot-build parent dependency is missig?

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, pom.xml

I know that when I am inheriting from `spring-boot-starter-parent` I'll have this inheritance chain:

my-project => [spring-boot-starter-parent](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-parent/pom.xml) => [spring-boot-dependencies](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml) => [spring-boot-build](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/pom.xml) => maven parent pom

=>(means inherit)

Indeed That's what I saw in Github. And I believe It is true.

But when I am navigating through these POMs on my IDE (IntelliJ) the `spring-boot-dependencies` does not declare a parent pom (which should be `spring-boot-build` according to GitHub)

[image: No parent pom specified]

Why there is no inheritance specified in `spring-boot-dependencies` in my IDE(**there is one GitHub**)? I am missing something?

### Edit

My project's pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I correctly understand your question: The given project with pom file is working? It looks fine...The point of the missing reference to the parent is correct cause the relationship to the parent is only needed during the build but not for consumption...

Comment: but still (and i would confirm) it looks like spring does't release "the same" pom, as it tagged for release (on github) ..and this is not only a intelliJ problem: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.2.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-dependencies-2.2.0.RELEASE.pom

Comment: The deploy a so called consumer pom file which is correct. Gradle does that for a longer time cause they don't have relationship between modules in their build ...etc. also Maven will go that path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't show the parent POM relation in your IDE, because in the pom file for spring-boot-dependencies, that's deployed to the central Maven repository, there is no parent tag: https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.2.0.RELEASE/pom
Eclipse will load that pom file, not the one from the source repository.

So it looks that the build process from Spring Boot removes the parent tag, when it's deploying the pom to Maven Central.

A reason for this could be (and the naming suggests it), that spring-boot-build only provides configuration and dependencies related to the build process for Spring Boot itself, but isn't necessary or desired for applications using it.

Comment: The last paragraph describes exactly the reason. The relationship between the modules is not relevant to consumers.